# Is it possible to create a win32 messaging window that won't be found by enumerating?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I'm trying to enumerate all win32 windows using following code:

```
EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(),
                 WindowManager::enumChildWindows,
                 reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));

BOOL CALLBACK WindowManager::enumChildWindows(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    WindowManager* manager = reinterpret_cast<WindowManager*>(lParam);

    //
    // Do stuff with child window handle (hwnd)
    //

    // Return TRUE to continue enumeration, FALSE to stop.
    return TRUE;
}
```

So basically, I get the top most window by calling `GetDesktopWindow( VOID )` function from WinAPI and enumerate child windows by calling `EnumChildWindows( __in_opt HWND hWndParent, __in WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, __in LPARAM lParam)` function again from WinAPI.

Simply, my question is, can I be missing any win32 window by this approach? Could anyone hide a win32 window such that this approach can't enumerate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that if the messaging window is hidden too well, then it won't get any messages, therefore it won't really be a messaging window... SO it has to be enumerated to work.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: well unless it's hidden by means of code injected in each user32.dll instance, by some rootkit. or the like. anyway, +1.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: I didn't quite get what you meant by _'won't get any messages'_. I can understand that it won't get `WM_PAINT` or `WM_SETCURSOR`, but how about `WM_USER` or any other custom message such as `WM_USER + n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your way (via EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow)) - it is possible: just create message-only window. 
 P.S. But you can enumerate message-only windows via EnumChildWindows(GetAncestor(FindWindowEx(HWND_MESSAGE,0,0,0),GA_PARENT)): see [How come FindWindow finds a window that EnumChildWindows doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518307/how-come-findwindow-finds-a-window-that-enumchildwindows-doesnt/15323045#15323045).